# Unable to read user define characteristics in bluetooth services (BLE) using iOS application

Tags: swift, iphone, ipad, bluetooth-lowenergy, objective-c-blocks

I am developing iOS app in that I'm using core BLE services and characteristics for read and write data.
Here I'm using service having unique CBUUID and this service having two default characteristics, I can able to read and write that characterisitcs but when we add another charecteristics in that service I'm unable to read that newly added characteristics.

**Please check code as follows**

**For scan peripheral device**

```
     var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
     centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
```

**After discover peripheral connect to particular device using following delegate methods**

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover          peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                    advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)

    {
         if(peripheral.name == "myBLE")
        {
            centralManager.stopScan()
            centralManager.connect(myPeripheral)
        }
    }
```

**After connecting bluetooth device, discover services**

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)
    {

        //centralManager.stopScan()
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)   // For all services

    }
```

**We get services in following delegate methods**

```
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)
    {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }

        for service in services
        {

            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)               
        }

    }
```

**We get charecteristics in following delegate methods**

```
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?)
    {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }

        for characteristic in characteristics
        {
            print(characteristic)

            //Here we get only default characteristics, but not getting newly added characteristics

            if characteristic.properties.contains(.read)
            {
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
            }

            if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify)
            {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }

        }

    }
```

**Here I am unable to read newly added characteristics, is there any solution please let me know.**

Comment: Can you explain why you are unable to read newly added characteristics? Do you get an error? Is there maybe a stacktrace?

Comment: No, I didn't get any error.

Comment: I observe that when we run application in iOS 11.3.1 it works but in iOS version 11.4.1 it doesn't work.